# How to replace numbers in string with link containing the same number

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a simple HTML page, containing lists of numbers. Like this:

> Look at the following pages: 23, 509, 209, 11, 139, 68, 70-72, 50, 409-412

I want to replace every number, or range with a hyperlink like that:

> `<a href="www.mysite.com?page=23">23</a>, <a href="www.mysite.com?page=509">509</a> ..... <a href="www.mysite.com?page=409">409-412</a>`

The numbers are only two and three digits and are enclosed in commas except the first and the last. And there are some ranges like 391-397

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried.

Comment: If I knew how you find the numbers, or how you get the numbers into a variable (or do you even have the numbers in a variable?), then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: You have to use php or javascript to do this, only html can not solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP `preg_replace()` to achieve what you want.

```
$original_string = 'Look at the following pages: 23, 509, 209, 11, 139, 68, 70-72, 50, 409-412';

$updated_string = preg_replace(
   '~((\d{2,3})(\-\d{2,3})?)~', 
   '<a href="//www.mysite.com?page=$2">$1</a>', 
   $original_string
);

echo $updated_string;
```

See it working [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8a480fdc101a9a74b3def0cf9d8634d9746851e).

The `()` sections in the first argument of `preg_replace()` can be referenced in the second argument with `$1`, `$2` etc... The first enclosed section (`$1`) is the page number or page range ("23", "70-72"). The second enclosed section (`$2`) is the page number or first number of the page range.

There's plenty of resources with more info on regex online, you can play around with the regex I've written [here](https://regex101.com/r/r4WxNx/1).

Answer (score 0):

this is only if you sure of the pattern of the source string

```
$numbers = "23, 509, 209, 11, 139, 68, 70-72, 50, 409-412";
$output = "";
$numbers = explode(",",$numbers);//split the string into array (NOTE:only if you trust the pattern of the string)

foreach($numbers as $number){
     $number = str_replace(" ","", $number); // remove the space that is after the comma if there is
     $range = explode("-",$number); // if it is a range it will be splitted
     $output .= "<a href='www.mysite.com?page=".$range[0]."'>$number</a> ";
}
echo $output;
```

HTML note: making the href attribute like this `www.mysite.com` will cause the browser to trail it's value after the current document location so it is going to be something like this

```
 https://www.example.com/currentlocation/www.mysite.com?page=23
```

I guess that is what you want

```
<a href='https://www.example.com?page=23'>
```